# What should be known to integrate an IP-KVM in a small business?

Tags: small-business, keyboard-video-mouse

What should be known to integrate an IP-KVM in a small business that is Windows server based? Also with this how should a person with little knowledge of IP-KVM hardware differentiate the inordinate amount of products available for what is most practical for the business?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking for an ipkvm you need to think of three things.
1 - reliability 
2 - features

If its for backdoor access if shit breaks one of the cheaper units on the market will do well.
http://www.aten.com/ make good little reliable units that work well and i have found to be solid.
They use a VNC interface, they are a little clunky over low bandwidth but good enough for OS installs and fixing broken things.

You can get units with virtual media ect but the price keeps going up.

A single port IPKVM connected to a normal KVM is useful if you require a single user to have access to many machines at a cost that is FAR less then multi port IPKVM units.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the checklist should be something like:

1) Reliability
2) IP Performance 
3) Absolute Mouse Synchronization
4) Security(probably with 256 AES)

As most of the professionals IP KVMs today are highly reliable, the main difference is in the remote performance and mouse synch. I would suggest you to do your own short online demo:

- www.belkin.com/kvm/demo/
- http://www.minicom.com/ipkvm-demo-request.cfm
- https://forms.raritan.com/contact/online-demo